# My Galaxy S6 Edge cannot connect to Android Studio via USB Debugging

Tags: android-studio, galaxy, usb-debugging

When I plug my Galaxy S6 Edge into my computer, Android Studio does not recognize it as an available USB device. I've tried to download a USB Driver update and I have USB Debugging checked on my phone, but nothing is working. What else do I need to do in order to run my app on my phone?

Comment: Did you download the device drivers - is that was you means by "tried to download a USB Driver". http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117. Also you can install Kies and that will probably find the correct drivers for you. Otherwise, take a look in your device manager,.. there are probably some clues there

Comment: I updated the device driver but my phone is still not recognized in Android Studio. Is there any other way to get my app on my phone?

Answer (score 18):

If your settings (S6 USB debugging, driver, Android Studio) are correct, you might try the following:

- (On phone) turn USB Debugging OFF
- Connect S6 to USB
- Click on the notification "connected as MTP device", check the option "camera" (also appropriate for non-MTP connection)
- turn USB Debugging back ON

If your device runs Android 6, the notification (step 3 above) should say "Use USB for" and offer 4 choices. You want to click on "Transferring Images".

Answer (score 5):

**I had the same problem. I tried with another USB cable (Not the one comes with my s6 edge or any samsung product ) and it worked.**

(prior to this i spend almost a day by installing some software and all :(..but only above solution worked for me )

Answer (score 2):

If you see the connected device in the "Other devices" of the Device Manager, try adding "Hardware Ids" of it to android_winusb.inf. Then select "Update Driver Software" in the Device Manager.
The detail can be found in the link below. In my environment, adb_usb.ini was not there, so I skipped it but could recognize my Galaxy S6 Edege.
http://jodieorourke.com/view.php?id=190&blog=news

Comment: I couldn't find android_winusb.inf but I looked at my SDK Manager and it had an update for the Google USB Driver. After I updated that, it worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. 
The android_winusb.inf is under <android_sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\android_winusb.inf
Just a note to the linked tutorial, I've not found the "adb_usb.ini" but it turns out that was not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Please use another USB cable which is not coming wth a Samsung mobile. it will work for sure. I wasted almost 2 days fixing this issue finally went out and buy another cable. It worked. No need for any other software change.

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways how to connect USB device.

- **MTP** - to enable remote computer browse device's files. Need to be accesible for windows explorer.
- **Camera** - device works as media (photos, videos, music) provider - these media  could be imported to other device like PC. Typical usage is with Photo managing SW on PC like Zoner Photo Studi, LightRoom, ...
- **MIDI** (Iam not sure, but another standard how to share music device)
- **Power only** - device does not provide any functions to connected computer, it use only its power over USB cable.

So, change type to MTP or CAMERA and android studio show see your device.
W

Comment: I tried to change evrything before changing the cable. But no idea what was ths issue with provided USB cable.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have enabled developers option this can be enabled by 7 times tapping on Build number in settings ---> About phone.

Comment: he has USB debugging checked so obviously he has the developer options enabled!

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm a bit late to answer, but maybe it will help other people in future. Me too I've got a Samsung S7 Edge, and couldn't debug with it. After some checking I realized that the reason is the Knox/My Knox. See here: https://seap.samsung.com/forum-topic/can-i-use-usb-debugging-mode-device-running-knox
What I've done is just go to playstore, found there My Knox and clicked Uninstall, then switched on  USB debugging in Developer options that was previously grayed out. 
(There are some other manuals on how to disable Knox. Some of them require rooting, but after rooting, I believe Samsung warranty will not work, if something happens to your phone. )