# USB debugging Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, driver, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy

I'm new to Android Studio and have a basic app written and ready to debug on my Samsung Galaxy S4 (I don't know if it even matters) which uses Android 4.3. I get the error "USB device not found" every time I run the app on Windows 7. I've done the following so far:

1. I've been to the SDK manager and installed the Google USB Driver
2. Set my device's Developer options on and USB debugging to on
3. I've also tried to reinstall my device driver using the Google USB driver

This has become very frustrating and hopeless because I don't know where to look for the problem. Does anyone have any ideas where my problem may be? I've tried restarting Android Studio, my device, my computer, I don't know what to do next.

I have tried the solutions posted in 
[My Galaxy S6 Edge cannot connect to Android Studio via USB Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002084/my-galaxy-s6-edge-cannot-connect-to-android-studio-via-usb-debugging) and tried various combinations of turning on the USB debugging feature before, I start Android Studio, after I start it, with the adb kill-server and adb start-server but I still have no luck.

My default installation location of my phone is set to sd card because my internal storage is running out - can this possibly have an impact?

Comment: do you see the device if you do `adb devices`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My Galaxy S6 Edge cannot connect to Android Studio via USB Debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32002084/my-galaxy-s6-edge-cannot-connect-to-android-studio-via-usb-debugging)

Comment: problem solved ? @Arshya Feyzi  ?

Comment: @F43nd1r it doesn't show anything. It says: List of devices attached
 and shows nothing

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi not yet

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to device driver issue. Connect your device to a computer and since you are using Windows, right click on "My computer" -> "Manage" -> "Device manager". Check if there is a device indicated with a small yellow warning message. If it is there, update the driver.

Comment: Thanks for your response
My device is shown correctly under the "Portable Devices". However, when I connect my phone I see yellow exclamation marks on an item called "Unknown Device" under "Other Devices". This used to be "SAMSUNG_ANDROID"  but it would always show as a yellow exclamation mark and had nothing to do with the "Portable Device" so I uninstalled it (I tried debugging with and without this driver - none worked :( )

Comment: Search for the `device driver` for your phone and install it. You can search it like `Samsung yourModel driver for windows` and then install it, [here](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117) is what I found for `S4` or else you can find the `general device driver `for `Samsung` devices from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/5kcxc1yovvl6740/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones%282%29.exe) and run debuging again and let me know the results

Answer (score 0):

Download this adb installer and install it in your System.
Your device automatically connect with Android Studio

http://adbdriver.com/downloads/