# Try to build flutter app on android studio, device not getting deetect

Tags: android, dart, flutter

When i try to create new app using flutter, app will get created  successfully but device or an emulator not getting detect it will show this message on clicking run

```
 No connected devices found; please connect a device, or see flutter.io/setup 
 for getting started instructions.
```

Comment: Try by closing device and restart it again.

Comment: For now it is not clear what's wrong, so try this -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49055266/1010710. In case it doesn't help - please update your question with more details (like "flutter doctor" and "adb devices" outputs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test android apps in a real device with Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947834/how-to-test-android-apps-in-a-real-device-with-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Try to close Android Studio with emulator opened, so Open Android Studio Again. If don't work, close emulator and search in SDK Manager if don't have any actualizations to emulator. Try connect a Android mobile and see if Android Studio detect it.

Last, reinstall all the stuffs, including Flutter and Dart (SDK and plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all the plugins and reinstall all the plugins again and then restart android studio.