# Could not update files on device: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received

Tags: android, flutter

I have build a flutter app and when try to run on older version of android API 16 it shows an error unfortunately app has stopped.In console it is showing an error could not update files on device: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:64386/UnbKN1wrm_A=/

Comment: This issue is coming because of one of the package conflict. I was getting this issue when I have use package called "flutter_facebook_login". When I tried to disable each package and run my application I found this issue and then I solved by doing necessary steps that were required by flutter facebook login package which was shown in https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

In the discussions opened in GitHub, it seems that the culprit of the error is the Android Q Emulator itself.

Here are the issues related to this:

- [Error connecting to the service protocol when using Android Q beta emulator image](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32587)
- [flutter run: Error connecting to the service protocol on Android Q (API level 29) emulator](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33050)

And since this is an emulator issue, I think the best option is to wait for the update or try to [run your Flutter app in a physical device as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879550/how-to-fix-httpexception-connection-closed-before-full-header-was-received).

Some temporary workaround if physical device is not available is to create another [emulated device like Pixel 2 Android 9.0 Target (28 API)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32587#issuecomment-492053752).