# How to reload a network image in flutter?

Tags: flutter

When using a network image in flutter sometimes I got the error `Connection closed before full header was received`. The code below allows me to output the error but how can I force the widget to reload the image?

```
Image.network(p.thumbURL,
  errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    Log.e(exception);
    return Container();
  },
),
```

Comment: The answer to this question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56114376/4980141

Comment: It also happens on a physical device. I also would like to reload the image if any other error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. give a value key to your image widget, otherwise it won't rebuild when you update your link

```
key: ValueKey(url),
```

2. update your url by adding a new meaningless query string at the end, e.g. adding a time

```
setState(() { 
    url = url.split('?r')[0] + '?r=' + DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
});
```