# Flutter post request returns Unhandled Exception: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri

Tags: flutter, http, post, httpclient, httpexception

I'm facing some strange issue when try to make an http post request through HttpClient and through http package and for both I receive:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = https://dumb.api.url/api/login
```

The strange thing is it works through postman, curl and if done natively on Android (Kotlin). Also, there is no VPN or whatever turned on.

I know there is a lot of similar questions, but none of them helped me.

I already tried using http package, HttpClient, ioClient, Dio to make a request. I also tried to set timeouts, use delays, using badCertificates callback, cleaning the project (flutter clean), restarting IDE and device and running this both on emulator and device.

Comment: Hi, did you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56942627/9707804

Comment: Yes, it didn't work. Plus, the issue from the link is regarding connecting to emulator. In my case I have problems with sending http request

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41573 ... you can check out this issue mate.

Comment: I've seen this one too) I've added to the question the things I tried

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the emulator with the error?

Comment: There is nothing useful in the logs except the line I posted, and app's just showing an empty screen with 1 button to make a request

Comment: did you solve it? did it happen with http or https?

Comment: Hey buddy. Did you resolve your issue?? This same has occurred to me also.

Comment: Do you have any more incite into the issue?

Comment: have had this occur with flutter app in real device as well, have you got this problem resolved somehow?

Answer (score 0):

From the logs provided, it looks like the request has timed out. Try creating a new Android virtual device with a different Android version or try wiping the data of the Android virtual device. This should help reset the network config of the device.