# E/flutter (10464): Error: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http:/

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am developing a flutter app connecting to a rest backend. When trying a POST request with data I get error

Unhandled Exception: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://79.xxx.yyy.zzz/api/Device/Login?param=U2FsdGVkX1%2BcQIyEN0rAHg%2Fo5lC7angM5weo30YxkMUU8r1yKM6ibUtc7me7rvLx

This is the POST call code:

```html
Future<HttpClientResponse> makePost(String param, String content) async {
  final context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;
  context.allowLegacyUnsafeRenegotiation = true;
  final client = HttpClient(context: context);
final request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse('http://xxx.yyy.zzz.242/api/Device/Login?param='+param) );
request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, "application/json;");
request.persistentConnection=false;
request.write(content);


final response = await request.close();

response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
  print(contents);
});
return response;

}
```

Already attempted:

- Downgrading  AVD to android Pie (API 28)
- Running on physical device instead of AVD
- DIO / HTTPCLient , both fail
- Tested a post with data against other dummy backend and worked
- Can't solve with info from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55879550/how-to-fix-httpexception-connection-closed-before-full-header-was-received?rq=4)

Notes:

- sending a POST without any data does not throw the error
- For triage purposes, I made an API client in C# , sending the same POST, and it works, so the server is OK.
- ignore the param parameter value that is out of discussion
- Sniffing with wireshark shows that the flutter app sends some request data in the inicital TCP packet before the POST packet. While the C# .net app sends the request data only in the HTTP POST packet.
- Already tried hitting another HTTP (no ssl) API with a GET request and obtained a response. So android settings is actually allowing HTTP traffic (see screenshot below)

.net:
[image]

flutter using httpclient
[image]

flutter using vanilla http

[image]

Traffic hitting another HTTP (no HTTPS) API
[image]

Flutter traffic sniffed with IONIJA
[image]

NETCORE app traffic Sniffed with IONIJA
[image]

Comment: Have you tried seeing the network traffic with a tool like Charles Proxy?

Comment: @tomerpacific yes thank you, i will expand the question with this info. I used wireshark and packets look very similar. Will updat with this info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine (using a vanilla `http` POST)...

Just a plain Dart (3.1.0) project - recommend you try that. (In Android, be sure to allow HTTP vs HTTPS.)

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(
        'http://xx.178.213.242/api/Device/Login?param=U2FsdGVkX1%2BcQIyEN0rAHg%2Fo5lC7angM5weo30YxkMUU8r1yKM6ibUtc7me7rvLx'),
    body: json.encode({
      'username': 'xxc3df44938584631b2d36020c03f3e6',
      'passwd': 'xxcb5dbc3fdc7164565ca9a61d8d1fa4',
    }),
  );
  print(response.headers);
}
```

[image]

Edit: After realizing that the server is rejecting the lower case content headers, here's a workaround using the lower level `HttpClient` that allows the header case to be preserved. This version seems to get a valid response.

```
  final jsonMap = {
    'username': '22c3df44938584631b2d36020c03f3e6',
    'passwd': 'f5cb5dbc3fdc7164565ca9a61d8d1fa4',
  };
  final httpClient = HttpClient();
  final request = await httpClient.postUrl(Uri.parse(
    'http://79.178.213.242/api/Device/Login?param=U2FsdGVkX1%2BcQIyEN0rAHg%2Fo5lC7angM5weo30YxkMUU8r1yKM6ibUtc7me7rvLc',
  ));
  final encode = utf8.encode(json.encode(jsonMap));
  request.headers.set(
    'Content-Type',
    'application/json',
    preserveHeaderCase: true,
  );
  request.headers.set(
    'Content-Length',
    encode.length.toString(),
    preserveHeaderCase: true,
  );
  request.add(encode);
  final response = await request.close();
  String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  httpClient.close();
  print(reply);
```

Comment: We just tried http (updating question) and keep observing the same behavior in wireshark. Would you please try sniffing the packet at your side? also what Android version and flutter version are you using?
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Comment: thank you. I tried reaching another HTTP API and gor response, so it means cleartext traffic is allowed in the device. Question updated.
Also note that if I comment out the  request.write(content) line the server does actually respond with  { "status": 9, "msg": "Login fail" }

Comment: I just tested with some dummy data and can get the error you see. However, I only get that error if I submit *invalid* JSON. So, with no body, we see login fail, with valid JSON it works (see my answer above) and with *invalid* JSON it gives the error you see.

Comment: thank you again.
I am not sure why flutter JSON is invalid, at least not something obvious to our eyes.
I have added two IONINJA sniffs. Do you spot something obvious in the JSON data?

Comment: I think I discovered the problem. Your server is not RFC compliant. It seems to require camel case header names - whereas the RFC says that headers are case insensitive. I used postman to send two identical requests one with the traditional `Content-Length` (worked ok) and one with exactly the same spelled `content-length` (server closes the socket)