# How to test app on a real android device using a MAC

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I followed the directions here [How to test android apps in a real device with Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947834/how-to-test-android-apps-in-a-real-device-with-android-studio) to test an app on a real android device, but it explains how to do so in Windows but not a MAC. How can I test an app on a real android device using an Android Studio that's installed on MAC?

Answer (score 1):

Testing on MAC is more easier than Windows because if you have android device which is from well-known company, you already have USB driver installed on MAC.

Follow these steps to test Android device on MAC.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Connect Android device via USB
3. Now you should able to see your device just like in below screenshot

[image: showing device connected to Android Studio]

4. If not try "Troubleshoot device connection" menu. see screenshot.
5. You are now good to go with running your app first time on MAC :)

Comment: @LouisaScheinost Have you tried "Troubleshoot device connections"?

Answer (score 0):

After trying *Troubleshoot device connection*, if you see a message like this:

> *- *Device is waiting for you to grant permission for USB debugging**

Go to Settings -> Developer options and Switch off and On again and it should show the message to allow connection.