# Android Webview app shows black screen when i open it

Tags: java, android, iframe, webview, html5-video

Android weview app I compiled in andriod studio crashes immediately with a blackscreen when I open it. The app uses an iframe embed url.Compiles fine but crashes with a black screen when I open it.

Why is it crashing?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView zwebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String Video;
        Video  = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/eGPbD-f0b_A\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        WebSettings webSettings = zwebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        zwebView.setInitialScale(1);
        zwebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        zwebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        zwebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        zwebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        zwebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        zwebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        zwebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        zwebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        zwebView.loadData(Video, "text/html", "utf-8");

        zwebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        zwebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request) {
                webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }
        });

        zwebView.loadUrl(Video);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just copy-paste your code and its working fine the video is loading in the webview so if you face issue can you kindly share the log details that what error you actually getting.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView zwebView = new WebView(this);

        String Video;
        Video  = "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/eGPbD-f0b_A\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        WebSettings webSettings = zwebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        zwebView.setInitialScale(1);
        zwebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        zwebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        zwebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        zwebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        zwebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        zwebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        zwebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        zwebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        zwebView.loadData(Video, "text/html", "utf-8");

        zwebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request) {
                webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                return true;
            }
        });

        zwebView.loadUrl(Video);

        setContentView(zwebView);
    }
}
```

Here is the code which I use and it's working. not crashing after all.

Comment: When I compile the app in android studio (with the build apk option) I down it from my pc to my phone and install it. Then when I run the app it gives me the message "My appliccation keeps stopping" error with a black screen.

Comment: why you don't use run options and run the app directly to your phone using USB debugging with this you can see the error logs

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Check this answer I think you get an idea -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/46007135/9212581