# How to configure my smartphone with intellij idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea

how do I use my smartphone as a debugger device in intellij Idea ide for debugging android apps.

Comment: Turn on developer options

Comment: I have done that in my phone but what to do in intellij ide... To configure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21947834/12478830

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test android apps in a real device with Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947834/how-to-test-android-apps-in-a-real-device-with-android-studio)

Comment: @MMG not in Android studio,

Comment: @MMG in intellij Idea ide

Comment: Android Studio is _extremely_ similar to IntelliJ IDEA...most of the code/functionality is the same.  Are you saying you've followed the steps in the question MMG linked and they did not work?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to --> Settings --> Additional Settings --> Developer Options -> USB DEBUGGING: Make it On
2. Go to --> Settings --> Additional Settings --> Developer Options -> INSTALL VIA USB make it On

If you don't see Developer Options

1. Go to --> Settings --> about device or about phone --> scroll down and find build number --> tap the build number seven times -> Enter password if asked. [image]

After all when you connect your to your computer
[image: Tap the shown area below and select Transfer Photos PTP]

[image]

Congratz ! Your device is now ready