# The best drivers for your device are already installed: installing Android device USB driver

Tags: android, android-studio, usb-drive

Windows 10 cannot recognize my mobile device connected via USB cable. Therefore, I'm following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42311045/3405291) to install Android SDK Google USB driver:

[image: Screenshot]

But Windows 10 doesn't allow me to replace the default Microsoft USB driver:

[image: Screenshot 1]

> The best drivers for your device are already installed

How can I install Google USB driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't do anything other than `Uninstall Device` a few times by *device manager* yesterday. But today, when I connect the mobile device to Windows 10 by USB cable, it is recognized and SAMSUNG driver is detected and used:

[image: Device manager screenshot]

Now flutter can detect the connected device:

[image: Flutter doctor screenshot]